# Error while installation of spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

I am facing the following error while trying to install spacemacs. I am presently on ubuntu 17.04.

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading '/home/User/.emacs.d/init.el'
>
> File error: Searching for program, Is a directory,

Here is the error code I get while opening on --debug-init:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Searching for program" "Is a directory" "")


call-process("" nil t nil "-c" "/usr/bin/timeout --help")
  apply(call-process "" nil t nil ("-c" "/usr/bin/timeout --help"))
  process-file("" nil t nil "-c" "/usr/bin/timeout --help")
  shell-command-to-string("/usr/bin/timeout --help")
  (string-match-p "^ *-k" (shell-command-to-string (concat prog " --help")))
  (and prog (string-match-p "^ *-k" (shell-command-to-string (concat prog " --help"))))
  (if (and prog (string-match-p "^ *-k" (shell-command-to-string (concat prog " --help")))) (progn prog))
  (when (and prog (string-match-p "^ *-k" (shell-command-to-string (concat prog " --help")))) prog)
  (let ((prog (or (executable-find "timeout") (executable-find "gtimeout")))) (when (and prog (string-match-p "^ *-k" (shell-command-to-string (concat prog " --help")))) prog))
  eval((let ((prog (or (executable-find "timeout") (executable-find "gtimeout")))) (when (and prog (string-match-p "^ *-k" (shell-command-to-string (concat prog " --help")))) prog)))
  custom-initialize-reset(package-build-timeout-executable (let ((prog (or (executable-find "timeout") (executable-find "gtimeout")))) (when (and prog (string-match-p "^ *-k" (shell-command-to-string (concat prog " --help")))) prog)))
  custom-declare-variable(package-build-timeout-executable (let ((prog (or (executable-find "timeout") (executable-find "gtimeout")))) (when (and prog (string-match-p "^ *-k" (shell-command-to-string (concat prog " --help")))) prog)) "Path to a GNU coreutils \"timeout\" command if available.\nThis must be a version which supports the \"-k\" option." :group package-build :type (file :must-match t))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-807180> nil "/home/sujit/.emacs.d/core/libs/package-build.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3283
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/sujit/.emacs.d/core/libs/package-build.el" "/home/sujit/.emacs.d/core/libs/package-build.el" nil t)
  require(package-build)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-522675> nil "/home/sujit/.emacs.d/core/libs/quelpa.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1420
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/sujit/.emacs.d/core/libs/quelpa.el" "/home/sujit/.emacs.d/core/libs/quelpa.el" nil t)
  require(quelpa)
  configuration-layer//configure-quelpa()
  (let ((display-buffer-alist (quote (("\\(\\*Compile-Log\\*\\)\\|\\(\\*Warnings\\*\\)" (display-buffer-in-side-window) (inhibit-same-window . t) (side . bottom) (window-height . 0.2)))))) (configuration-layer//configure-quelpa) (let* ((upkg-names (configuration-layer//get-uninstalled-packages packages)) (not-inst-count (length upkg-names)) installed-count) (if upkg-names (progn (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line "Installing packages...") (spacemacs//redisplay) (let ((delayed-warnings-backup delayed-warnings-list)) (spacemacs-buffer/append (format "Found %s new package(s) to install...\n" not-inst-count)) (configuration-layer/retrieve-package-archives) (setq installed-count 0) (spacemacs//redisplay) (let ((--dolist-tail-- upkg-names) pkg-name) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq pkg-name ...) (setq installed-count ...) (configuration-layer//install-package ...) (setq --dolist-tail-- ...))) (spacemacs-buffer/append "\n") (if init-file-debug nil (setq delayed-warnings-list delayed-warnings-backup)))))))
  configuration-layer//install-packages((ace-jump-helm-line ace-link ace-window adaptive-wrap aggressive-indent async auto-compile auto-highlight-symbol avy bind-key bind-map clean-aindent-mode column-enforce-mode define-word desktop diminish dumb-jump elisp-slime-nav eval-sexp-fu evil evil-anzu evil-args evil-ediff evil-escape evil-exchange evil-iedit-state evil-indent-plus evil-lisp-state evil-matchit evil-mc evil-nerd-commenter evil-numbers evil-search-highlight-persist evil-surround evil-tutor evil-unimpaired evil-visual-mark-mode evil-visualstar exec-path-from-shell expand-region eyebrowse fancy-battery fill-column-indicator flx-ido golden-ratio google-translate helm helm-ag helm-descbinds helm-flx ...))
  (let ((packages (append (configuration-layer/filter-objects configuration-layer--used-distant-packages (function (lambda (x) (let ... ...)))) (if (eq (quote all) dotspacemacs-install-packages) (progn (let (all-other-packages) (let ... ...) (configuration-layer//get-distant-packages all-other-packages nil))))))) (configuration-layer//install-packages packages) (if (and (or (eq (quote used) dotspacemacs-install-packages) (eq (quote used-only) dotspacemacs-install-packages)) (not configuration-layer-force-distribution) (not configuration-layer-exclude-all-layers)) (progn (configuration-layer/delete-orphan-packages packages))))
  (if no-install nil (let ((packages (append (configuration-layer/filter-objects configuration-layer--used-distant-packages (function (lambda ... ...))) (if (eq (quote all) dotspacemacs-install-packages) (progn (let ... ... ...)))))) (configuration-layer//install-packages packages) (if (and (or (eq (quote used) dotspacemacs-install-packages) (eq (quote used-only) dotspacemacs-install-packages)) (not configuration-layer-force-distribution) (not configuration-layer-exclude-all-layers)) (progn (configuration-layer/delete-orphan-packages packages)))))
  configuration-layer/sync()
  (if (not (version<= spacemacs-emacs-min-version emacs-version)) (error (concat "Your version of Emacs (%s) is too old. " "Spacemacs requires Emacs version %s or above.") emacs-version spacemacs-emacs-min-version) (load-file (concat (file-name-directory load-file-name) "core/core-load-paths.el")) (require (quote core-spacemacs)) (spacemacs/init) (configuration-layer/sync) (spacemacs-buffer/display-startup-note) (spacemacs/setup-startup-hook) (require (quote server)) (if (server-running-p) nil (server-start)))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/sujit/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1264
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/sujit/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/sujit/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/sujit/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\266\00 \306=\203\00\307\310Q\202?\00 \311=\204\00\307\312Q\202?\00\313\307\314\315#\203*\00\316\202?\00\313\307\314\317#\203>\00\320\321\322!D\nB\323\202?\00\316\324\325\324\211#\210\324=\203e\00\326\327\330\307\331Q!\"\325\324\211#\210\324=\203d\00\210\203\247\00\332!\333\232\203\247\00\334!\211\335P\336!\203\201\00\211\202\214\00\336!\203\213\00\202\214\00\314\262\203\245\00\337\"\203\243\00\340\341#\210\342\343!\210\266\f?\205\264\00\314\325\344\324\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the SHELL environment variable:

SHELL=/bin/bash emacs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have found the solution [thanks to Seanjamesking](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/11273#issuecomment-526864668)

Add

```
(require 'package) (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")) (package-initialize)
```

to the top of the `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file.

**I am using Emacs 25.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.3*